# Why tame automorphisms are important?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, automorphism-group, affine-varieties

It is known by Jung--van der Kulk theorem that any polynomial automorphism of $\mathbb{A} ^2$ is tame. It is known that in dimension 3 there are wild automorphisms.

My question is what are the good properties of tame polynomial automorphisms? Why are they interesting?